# What Happened To Men In the Soviet Union?

Tags: soviet-union

[Ignoring the question but trying to understand the context of one part of the answer](https://www.quora.com/What-are-unintended-consequences-of-the-metoo-movement):

> Men disappearing , Soviet style

I searched for what this could mean and came up with nothing.  Many Soviet men died in WW2 and women's population was larger than men in the Soviet Union after the war (WW2).  How did men disappear in the Soviet Union historically, or what could this be referring to in the Soviet Union?

Comment: Aren't they simply referring to the Stalin-era act of "airbrushing" people out of history?

Comment: After reading it, I suspect about 90% of your issue with understanding things in that answer is because the entire thing is utter nonsense. You'd really have to query the author with followup questions to have any hope of understanding any of the specific notions rattling around in his head (and I wouldn't suggest doing so without a big stockpile of [brain bleach](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrainBleach))

Comment: To equate the impact of the *#metoo* movement with Soviet-style (and other "disappeared") people "is frankly nonsense!

Comment: During Stalin times, when somebody was declared enemy of the people, their immediate family was arrested as well, and their close friends were investigated. Talking about arrest would be considered subversion. So if somebody was arrested, everybody else would basically pretend that the person did not ever exist. Ironically, 20 years later, Krushev has tried to eliminate Stalin himself from history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your link now brought me to the me too discussion on Quora. I advise to post a better link in your question.

Don’t know if this is what you are looking for but Stalin and his organisations structurally let people disappear. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulag
Stalin had more people killed than Hitler. And to the Gulags can be added the people who tried to escape the Soviet Union and were shot down.

Comment: I think that was in fact the exact link the poster intended, not an error. The quote is within it (as is a whole lot of other nonsense). I can come up with *theories* for what was meant by it in that quora poster's paranoia-addled mind, and this would be one of them, but I don't think there's really any way to tell for sure which he meant (without asking him), and I'm not sure this is the best website to be fielding "Can you interpret this mad internet rando's ravings?" questions.

Comment: Well you are right but we can answer the question about the Soviet ways of having men or people in general disappear. That aside fromraving rando’s. 

Comment: well again, there are multiple things he could have meant by that. This is only one of them. For example, the Soviets had a habit of removing famous people they no longer liked from history books. There's also the "disappeared" sense that is used in modern despotisims and lawless areas, where a person is simply extra-judiciously taken, and nobody even admits to it. I don't think the Soviets were big on that one. Gulags were kind of their Thing.

Comment: (On further reflection, I'm upvoting this though. I appreciate the effort you made as a new user to attempt to answer this, rather than just throw bricks like I and a lot of others did).

Comment: Helpful answer. The linked poster came off as crazy but I felt curious if the post had any verity with "men disappearing soviet style" (missed the reference). For an MD, he made some grammar mistakes.